# Is is possible to inject to .net core DI container the IAgent interface

Tags: .net-core, newrelic

I'm using NewRelic to gain insight on my system, In order to add custom attribute to the new-relic's transaction, I'm resolving the `IAgent` interface with `NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.GetAgent()` ([docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api/getagent/))

Like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod([FromBody]MyRequest request)
{
    //Do Some logic.

    IAgent agent = NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.GetAgent();
    ITransaction transaction = agent.CurrentTransaction;
    transaction.AddCustomAttribute("MyCustomAttribute", SomeValue)

    return Ok(...);
}
```

Is it possible to use the dependency injection container in order to resolve the `IAgent` interface? like:

```
[ApiController]
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IAgent _agnet;
    public MyController(IAgent agent)
    {
        _agent = agent;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod([FromBody]MyRequest request)
    {
         //Do Some logic.

         ITransaction transaction = this._agent.CurrentTransaction;
         transaction.AddCustomAttribute("MyCustomAttribute", SomeValue)

         return Ok(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hence it's a static instance, it can be registered as a singleton:

```
services.AddSingletone<IAgent>(NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.GetAgent());
```

or:

```
services.AddSingletone(NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.GetAgent());
```

Don't forget to configure the agent first, then add it to `IServiceCollection`.